# Update Outcome using xConnect client

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets

Sitecore: 9.0.2

I am trying to update xDB for contacts with the `Outcome`.
The source of data is from third party, so I cannot go through Tracker.

I am using the following code snippet
Code snippet:

```
Interaction webInteraction = new Interaction(existingContact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, new Guid(Constants.Analytics.ChannelId), "Website");
     Outcome outcome = new Outcome(new Guid(Constants.MarketingGoals.ProductPurchaseOutcome), date, currency, amount);
     webInteraction.Events.Add(outcome);
     client.AddInteraction(webInteraction);
     client.Submit();
```

But this is not getting updated against `InteractionsCache` facet. I do not see any error related to it.

What I am missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add surrounding code to the code snippet that is currently in your question? Especially how you instantiate client... –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Sitecore Support team for helping.

In case someone else also gets into this issue:

xConnect has the following configuration:

```
<ICalculatedFacetHandler.InteractionsCacheHandler>
<Type>Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.Plugins.InteractionsCacheHandler, Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.Plugins</Type>
<As>Sitecore.XConnect.Service.ICalculatedFacetHandler, Sitecore.XConnect.Service</As>
<LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
<Options>
<MaximumInteractionCount>42</MaximumInteractionCount>
<MaximumCacheEntryCount>50</MaximumCacheEntryCount>
<MaximumInteractionPeriod>30.00:00:00</MaximumInteractionPeriod>
</Options>
</ICalculatedFacetHandler.InteractionsCacheHandler>
```

The interaction I was trying to insert was of 2015, which was quite older than 30 days.
Hence I had this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Is this in Sitecore Context or outside the context (aka a raw call to xConnect)

### In Sitecore Context

Habitat has a good example of this https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/2d3ee809fa4035a46a410d0438ed41e1c7f8a3b1/src/Foundation/SitecoreExtensions/code/Services/TrackerService.cs#L100

OutcomeDefinitionManager comes from DI `IDefinitionManager<IOutcomeDefinition> outcomeDefinitionManager`

```
public void TrackOutcome(Guid outComeDefinitionId)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(outComeDefinitionId, nameof(outComeDefinitionId));

    if (!this.IsActive || Tracker.Current.Contact == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var outcomeDefinition = this.OutcomeDefinitionManager.Get(outComeDefinitionId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (outcomeDefinition == null)
    {
        Log.Warn($"Cannot find outcome: {outComeDefinitionId}", this);
        return;
    }
    Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterOutcome(outcomeDefinition, "USD", 0);
}
```

### Raw xConnect

This Sitecore doco has the code you need. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/add-interaction-events.html

```
using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    try
    {
        var contact = new Sitecore.XConnect.Contact();

        var channel = Guid.NewGuid(); // Use real channel ID from Sitecor

        var interaction = new Interaction(contact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, channel, "iTunes/9.0.3 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; en-ca)"); // Agent is iTunes

        Guid outcomeId = Guid.Parse("{21EC2020-3AEA-4069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"); // ID of outcome item

        var outcome = new Sitecore.XConnect.Outcome(outcomeId, DateTime.UtcNow, "USD", 100.00m);

        interaction.Events.Add(outcome);

        client.AddContact(contact);
        client.AddInteraction(interaction);

        await client.SubmitAsync();
    }
    catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

### Look in SQL

You can look in SQL to see your custom interaction with the custom outcome on the event. You just need the contact Id from the code.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [InteractionId]
      ,[LastModified]
      ,[Created]
      ,[ConcurrencyToken]
      ,[ContactId]
      ,[StartDateTime]
      ,[EndDateTime]
      ,[Initiator]
      ,[DeviceProfileId]
      ,[ChannelId]
      ,[VenueId]
      ,[CampaignId]
      ,[Events]
      ,[UserAgent]
      ,[EngagementValue]
      ,[Percentile]
  FROM [Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]
  WHERE ContactId = 'A86801E3-A35E-0000-0000-058CDEB592D7'
```

Comment: I am using the second way as you have mentioned. But it is not getting updated.

Comment: Can you log the contact ID when you process one and then query SQL to see if you can see it. I added the SQL to my answer above. I am wondering if it is working and you just can't see it in XP.

Comment: I was checking in xDB only. Presently I am re-deploying all the marketing definitions.  as I see 'Dimension could not be resolved for for dimension id: f81ef8cb-2662-491c-8f0f-da858dbddf54'. Not sure if they are related. Let's see.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work.

Comment: I know you are using the 2nd snippet of code, but are you running this in your sitecore website. Or from a remote site, like a console app?

Comment: I am running it in Sitecore context.

Comment: Then you should use code snippet #1. I bet it is creating the interactions, but the contact is wrong. Using snippet #1 is less lines of code and will work.

Comment: I will use snippet 1 for current users. Right now I am importing the old data from an excel file as a source.